# What's binary class matrix in context of deep learning?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I came through this while using 'to_categorical()' method in Keras

```
man = np.random.randint(10,20,10)
print(man)
man = ku.to_categorical(man)
print(man)
```

I want to know what exactly happens inside `to_categorical()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to_categorical behave like onehotencoding technique

if your particular categories is present then it mark as 1 else 0 in remain row

[image]

[image]